# How to set the height of a Data Grid in Silverlight 4

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a couple of DataGrids inside a page and each DataGrid is positioned via the following layout/markup:

```
<border BorderBrush="Black">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Title" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="6,0,0,0" Content="Panel Title"/>
        <toolkit:BusyIndicator Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="GridLoadingIndicator">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <sdk:DataGrid x:name="GVData" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                    SelectionMode="Single">
                    <datagrid:DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 1" Binding="{Binding Col1}" />                              
                    <datagrid:DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 2" Binding="{Binding Col2}" />                              
                    <datagrid:DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 3" Binding="{Binding Col3}" />                              
                    <datagrid:DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 4" Binding="{Binding Col4}" />                              
                    <datagrid:DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 5" Binding="{Binding Col5}" />
                </sdk:DataGrid>
            </StackPanel>
        </toolkit:BusyIndicator>
        <StackPanel x:Name="PagerControls" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <!-- Pager -->
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</border>
```

Well, the problem is that the grid itself doesn't want to stretch to fill the space allotted for it, and more over it doesn't respond to page size events either.

Any ideas on how to fix the issue?

Comment: Any reason the grid is in a stack panel?

Comment: I tried it with a border and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derek Beattie is correct in his comment.

If your `Grid` is within a `StackPanel` and the `StackPanel` does not have `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` (i.e. in the direction that does not grow) then the stack panel will fit its children.

This voids the `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` in your `Grid` as it can only stretch to its immediate parent (the `StackPanel`). The fact that it is a `StackPanel` means that `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` does nothing on the inner Grid.

If you actually require the inner `StackPanel` (no point with only one child), then add `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` to it as well. That will not do anything to the vertical stretch.

Personally I would just dump the `StackPanel` that surrounds the inner `Grid` as it add no value.

Comment: Even with HorizonatlAlignment="Stretch" and VerticalAlignment="Stretch" on the stack panel it still produced the same issues. As @Derek Beattie suggested I changed the stack panel to border and everything was fine.

Comment: *StackPanels as for stacking* as they say :) With your current design you do not need a border either, just the grid itself. Is there a reason you nested it in another control?